# Indicating imparfait in indirect reporting as coming from présent or imparfait

Tags: discours-indirect

I understand that both présent and imparfait in direct speech become imparfait in indirect reporting.

But suppose someone said:

> Je sais et je savais.

(It is an example I made up and so may not be idiomatic.)

If someone else was reporting that later on, that would give us (by the rule cited above):

> Elle dit qu'elle savait et qu'elle savait.

**QUESTION**

1. Is that, at least technically, perfectly correct indirect reporting?
2. Is there any standard device for indicating whether imparfait in indirect reporting came from présent or imparfait in the actual utterance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Je sais et je savais.* est correct, mais un peu *bizarre* prononcé seul. Généralement, il y a un contexte: appuyé sous forme oral, ou avec quelques compléments : je sais maintenant, et je savais déjà.

Relaté au passé, **on ne dirait pas** *Elle dit qu'elle savait et qu'elle savait.* . Ce n'est pas incorrect syntaxiquement, mais cela paraît **n'avoir aucun sens** de redoubler *savait*.

Il faudrait rajouter les compléments précédents:

> Elle dit qu'elle savait alors et qu'elle savait avant.
>
> Elle dit qu'elle savait alors et qu'elle savait déjà.

Souvent, on précise *quoi*:

> Elle dit qu'elle le savait alors et qu'elle le savait déjà.

En employant un plus-que-parfait, on peut aussi dire:

> Elle dit qu'elle savait et qu'elle l'avait (déjà) su.

Comment: Thank you. Could it be that the last method (the one using plus-que-parfait) is the best, or at least purest, as involving the least editorializing? After all, the original speaker didn't say *alors* or *déjà* (where, for instance, oral emphasis or some previous question provided the context).

Comment: Plus ou moins. Il peut y avoir plusieurs interprétations: 1  il y a plusieurs sources: je le sais (maintenant car tu me le dis), et je le savais (avant, de quelqu'un d'autre) ou bien 2 : je le sais (maintenant), et je le savais (il y a longtemps), mais j'avais oublié entretemps, ou encore 3 : je le sais et (rectification) je le savais (déjà).