# Le plus-que-parfait peut-il prendre le rôle de l'imparfait ?

Tags: verbes, temps-grammatical, concordance-des-temps, discours-indirect

Je sais que le plus-que-parfait exprime une action antérieure à un autre fait dans le passé. Mais est-ce que c'est toujours le cas lorsque cette action a duré dans le passé et est probablement inachevée ?

Par exemple, la phrase

> Elle me dit qu'elle a rédigé un livre.

n'a clairement pas les mêmes connotations que

> Elle me dit qu'elle rédigeait un livre.

La première signifie que la personne en question a fini de rédiger son bouquin ; la deuxième implique seulement qu'elle a consacré du temps à la rédaction et ne dit rien sur le résultat.

Ma question est la suivante : dans le deuxième exemple, comment devrais-je ajuster la subordonnée, si la principale était au passé composée ? La phrase deviendrait-elle

> Elle m'a dit qu'elle avait rédigé un livre.

ou plutôt

> Elle m'a dit qu'elle rédigeait un livre.

? Selon moi, les deux variantes sont problématiques. Dans le premier cas, la distinction présente dans les exemples originaux disparait : rien n'indique plus que la rédaction a duré dans le passé et est probablement inaccomplie (ce qui est mon but). Dans le deuxième cas, rien n'exprime l'antériorité de la subordonnée par rapport à la principale ; un interlocuteur pourrait penser que l'action de dire et l'action de rédiger sont simultanées.

Comment: Question un peu similaire : https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/18305/indicating-imparfait-in-indirect-reporting-as-coming-from-pr%c3%a9sent-or-imparfait

Answer (score 3):

Soyez heureux, la langue française vous donne toutes les possibilités. Votre deuxième phrase ne vous semble pas assez précise ? précisez donc:

```
Elle m'a dit qu'à l'époque elle rédigeait un livre.
Elle m'a dit qu'elle était en train de rédiger un livre.
```

Il n'y a pas de règle stricte parce qu'après "Elle me dit" ou "Elle m'a dit" vous pouvez dire ... ce que vous voulez dire ! ;) :

```
Elle m'a dit qu'elle rédigera un livre.
Elle m'a dit qu'elle aurait pu rédiger un livre.
Elle m'a dit qu'elle rédige un livre.
```

La phrase "Elle m'a dit qu'elle rédigeait un livre" est << large >> mais "Elle me dit qu'elle rédigeait un livre" itou, rien ne précise qu'elle l'a fini ou pas ce livre. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Je vais accompagner @jcm69 en disant qu'en français on a plusieurs forme de temps.

Dans tes exemples je perçois le **présent historique** qui est très dynamique. Le plus important c'est **la succession des actions dans le temps**.

Pour moi la meilleure concordance serait
`Elle m'a dit qu'elle avait rédigé un livre` ...

En conclusion **l'imparfait ne pourra jamais prendre la place du plus que parfait**

**Plus que parfait** sous-entend que "tout s'est bien passé "

**Imparfait** sous-entend que quelque chose a interrompu le processus ...

Answer (score 0):

Généralement, les temps composés expriment une action accomplie alors que les temps simples expriment une action inaccomplie.

Ainsi, lorsque l’on utilise l’imparfait, on considère l’action en cours de réalisation dans le passé. Lorsque l’on utilise le plus que parfait, on considère l’action accomplie, c’est à dire du début à la fin.
D’autre part, le plus que parfait permet d’exprimer une action antérieure à l’imparfait.

Elle m’a dit qu’elle avait rédigé un livre : la rédaction du livre est terminée.

Elle m’a dit qu’elle rédigeait un livre : on considère la rédaction du livre en cours dans le passé et cette rédaction n’est pas forcément terminée dans le présent.